# Ubuntu 16.04 Laptop with Nvidia and Intel 3+ monitor configuration

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, cuda

I have an Alienware 14 running dual Intel HD4600 and Nvidia
765M graphics. I am trying to connect two external monitors and run the laptop screen at the same time.

If I use the Nouveau driver for my Nvidia I can attach two external monitors to my laptop and have the laptops screen itself as a third monitor.  Everything works, but the Nvidia capabilities are limited... CUDA etc.

When I install the various Nvidia drivers it doesn't seem to work and I can only run the laptop screen and one external monitor. But then I can use gpu computing with CUDA etc.

Surely it must only be setup or configuration settings preventing me from using all three monitors with the Nvidia drivers if the Nouveau drivers can do this???

I've looked at all the open thread and none seem to have solutions. Can someone please assist.